# How to provide string formatting for structs?

Tags: string, struct, go

I've a struct called item

```
type Item struct {
    Limit int
    Skip int
    Fields string
}



item := Item {
            Limit: 3,
            Skip: 5,
            Fields: "Valuie",
    }
```

how could I get the field name, value and join it into a string.

something like:

```
item := Item {
            Limit: 3,
            Skip: 5,
            Fields: "Valuie",
    }
```

to a string something like

```
"Limit=3&Skip=5&Fields=Valuie"
```

---

And I've try reflections to get convert interface to field value map so far. Am I going the right way? Cause I think there might have some better solutions. And thanks!

```
m, _ = reflections.Items(data)
for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Printf("%s : %s\n", k, v)
}
```

I've got

```
Limit : %!s(int=3)
Skip : %!s(int=5)
Fields : Valuie
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use %v instead of %s. %s will assume a string, something that can be converted to a string (i.e. byte array) or an object with a String() method.
Using %v will check the type and display it correctly.

Example of the String() method call with %s with your example: http://play.golang.org/p/bxE91IaVKj

Comment: sorry, what's `v = &url.Values{}` for?

Comment: It look like you try to forge url values. url.Values is a map with couple of method to help with it. You could remove it and forge it yourself with Sprintf.

Comment: For further question, how could I join the string I create and back to the url? Something like `http://localhost:3000/?limit=3&skip=5` Is there any simple solution?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/SjBMmR2InT ?

Comment: @creack You did not provide the full answer. Please consider including the relevant code in your answer and don't rely on external sites.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use reflection for this. Just write out the code for the types you have.

```
func (i *Item) URLValues() string {
    uv := url.Values()
    uv.Set("Limit", strconv.Itoa(i.Limit))
    uv.Set("Skip", strconv.Itoa(i.Skip))
    uv.Set("Fields", i.Fields)
    return uv.Encode()
}
```

This code is simple, readable, and you don't need to think to write it. Unless you have a *lot* of types that you're going to be converting to values then I'd not even think about the magic reflection-based solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For any struct you can use reflection and [`url.Values`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) from the `net/url` package:

```
i := Item{1, 2, "foo"}

v := url.Values{}
ri := reflect.ValueOf(i)

ri.FieldByNameFunc(func(name string) bool {
    v.Set(name, fmt.Sprintf("%v", ri.FieldByName(name).Interface()))
    return false
})

fmt.Println(v.Encode())
```

[Example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/IeJBD5mBUb).

Of course, this code does not handle nested data structures or slices so you would need to extend
the code if you use other data structures to make it more general. However, this example should
get you started.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't seem to be working. The string field isn't  called by FieldByNameFunc.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed the example. `FieldByNameFunc` aborts the search when `true` is returned so `false` is the correct value here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [go-querystring](https://github.com/google/go-querystring). It converts a struct into URL query parameters (your expected output).

```
type Item struct {
  Limit  int    `limit:"limit"`
  Skip   int    `url:"skip"`
  Fields string `url:"fields"`
}

item := Item {
  Limit: 3,
  Skip: 5,
  Fields: "Valuie",
}

v, _ := query.Values(item)
fmt.Print(v.Encode()) 
// will output: "limit=3&skip=5&fields=Valuie"
```